# error in where statement in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

```
function get_place_info1($latitude,$longitude)
    {
        $t=round($latitude,4);
        $t1=round($longitude,4);
        $this->db->select('name');
        $this->db->from('place');
        $this->db->where(round('Latitude',4), $t);
        $this->db->where(round('Longitude',4),$t1);
        $q = $this->db->get();
        $res = $q->result();
        return $res;
    }
```

---

$latitude and $longitude are double and i want to round them but when i execute it give me that mistake

```
Error Number: 1054  
Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'
SELECT `name` FROM (`place`) WHERE `0` = 33.5041 AND `0` = 36.3033
Filename: C:\wamp\www\tourism\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 330
```

what's wrong with it?

Comment: The column `name` doesn't seem to exist in the `place` table.

Comment: Can you post your table structure?

Comment: please format your code. Cant understand anything.

Comment: @Sos Please use the CODE markdown to format your code.

Comment: your database structure please.

Answer (score 2):

The 'name' column doesn't seem to exists in the database table.

Also, you are performing a float round call on a string

> round('Latitude',4)

where you should probably just enter the field name. But that's hard to say without the database schema

```
$this->db->where('Latitude', $t);
$this->db->where('Longitude',$t1);
```

Comment: the column name wasn't name it was place_name thx                                              put now it give me that's wrong                                     -------   Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '0' in 'where clause'

SELECT `place_name` FROM (`place`) WHERE `0` = 33.5041 AND `0` = 36.3033

Filename: C:\wamp\www\tourism\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330                                                     what's wrong with it?

Comment: the place table contains "latitude double PK , longitude double PK ,place_name varchar , history text"

Comment: Then your column names shouldn't be capitalized, but that shouldn't be an issue in MySQL.  The issue is `round('any non-numeric string', 4)` -- it will always give you a zero value, which the DB class is then taking as a column name.